# Run method from UnCaughtException Handler

Tags: objective-c

How do I call a method from an UncaughtExceptionHandler? I've got this...

```
void onUncaughtException(NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"uncaught exception: %@", exception.description);
    [self playerLoggedOut];
}
```

But it's giving me an error at `[self playerLoggedOut];`

Comment: this is C function, so what do you expect for `self`?

Comment: ok so I can create a normal Obj-c exception handler? is there any reason it needs to be in C?

Answer (score 0):

`onUncaughtException` is a function, not a method. It isn't running 'on' an instance, it's just running. So `self` isn't defined in the context of the function. You need some other way to refer to `self` (possibly via a singleton) or some other way to perform your desired functionality.

Comment: ok so I can create a normal Obj-c exception handler? is there any reason it needs to be in C?

Comment: No, it needs to be a C function because that is the defined interface.

Comment: All I want to do is run a method, when there's an uncaught exception, so you're saying there's no way to do that? Can you give me an example?

Comment: You can't directly do it. If it must be a method call then you need some way to get to the instance. You should try to steer clear of method calls though as you can't guarantee the state of the object. Try to do the minimum possible and using only known (preferably static) information.